# redirect domain to another domain (and path)

Tags: domain, subdomain

I have my wordpress blog at **firstdomain.com/blog** and I want to access the blog as **seconddomain.com**. How do I set up **seconddomain.com** to make it happen?

**EDIT:**
If I'm not wrong, the steps involved are:

1. forward the domain seconddomain.com to blog.firstdomain.com (I have created blog.firstdomain.com subdomain)
2. forward blog.firstdomain.com to firstdomain.com/blog

I want to do so in such a way that:

1. At the end of this setting, when i click on seconddomain.com/abc, it points to firstdomain.com/blog/abc
2. The address bar shows seconddomain.com/abc even after redirection mentioned in #1
3. The approach is SEO friendly.
4. When I hover on the link on the blog, the status bar should display seconddomain.com/... and not firstdomain.com/blog/...

Comment: Can you use an `.htaccess` file?

Comment: on firstdomain.com? yes

Comment: use .htaccess http://ndesign-studio.com/blog/301-htaccess-redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is dependent on what kind of providers you use for both domain and hosting, what they use as software and possibly what sort of control panels they offer. It does not sound like you do the hosting yourself, but then the answer would be: Point seconddomain.com to the same IP as firstdomain.com (by modifying the A record), and use VirtualHost or similar directives on the (web) server to deliver the content that is currently served by firstdomain.com/blog when people access seconddomain.com. Then you might want to redirect firstdomain.com/blog/* to seconddomain.com/* .

It's really not easy to answer without knowing details. If both domains and hosting are maintained by someone for you, it's best to ask there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by using the `domain forwarding` option. In your **domain control panel** you can find the option to `forward your domain`, if not ask your domain name registrar and make use of that service. In your `seconddomain.com`, just put the forwarding **path** to `firstdomain.com/blog.`